# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have created a Provider and I wanted to test it. I'm creating a mock Component inside of test file

// TasksProvider.spec.tsx

```
const task = {
  name: 'New Task',
}

function TestComponent() {
  const { tasks, addTask, deleteTask } = useContext(TasksContext)

  return (
    <>
      <p data-testid="value">{...tasks}</p>
      <button onClick={() => addTask(task)}>Add Task</button>
      <button onClick={() => deleteTask(task)}>Delete Task</button>
    </>
  )
}

describe('Tasks Provider', () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <TasksProvider>
        <TestComponent />
      </TasksProvider>
    )
  })

  it('Add task', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="value"]').text()).toEqual('')

    wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate('click')

    expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="value"]').text()).toEqual(task)
  })

  it('Delete task', () => {
    wrapper.find('button').at(1).simulate('click')

    expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="value"]').text()).toEqual('')
  })
})
```

Like you can see there are two buttons. They have two different jobs one deleting task and one adding.

```
wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate('click')
```

(Using this first button that should add task)
And when I tried to use that line i got error

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

But when I'm using second button i don't have any errors and test passes.

//TasksProvider.tsx

```
interface TasksContextType {
  tasks: ITask[]
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  addTask(task: ITask): void
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  deleteTask(taskToDelete: ITask): void
}

export const TasksContext = createContext<TasksContextType>({
  tasks: [],
  addTask: () => {},
  deleteTask: () => {},
})

const TasksProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<ITask[]>([])

  const addTask = (task: ITask) => setTasks([task, ...tasks])

  function deleteTask(taskToDelete: ITask) {
    const filteredTasks = tasks.filter(task => task !== taskToDelete)
    setTasks(filteredTasks)
  }

  return (
    <TasksContext.Provider
      value={{
        tasks,
        addTask,
        deleteTask,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </TasksContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default TasksProvider
```

Comment: try `const task = 'New Task';`

Comment: task is an object there is interface for task

export interface ITask {
  id?: string
  name: string
}

Comment: So, is `tasks` an array of { id?: string name: string } objects in your TasksContext? What is the default values of `tasks`?

Comment: I added all TasksProvider file that you can see everything. Default value of tasks is an empty array `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error in this line:
`<p data-testid="value">{...tasks}</p>`. if `tasks` is an array then you need to map over it. And since `task` contains two property `id` and `name`, then the below code snippet should work for you.

```
{
 tasks.map((task)=> 
(
  <div>
    <p>{task.id}</p>
    <p>{task.name}</p>
  </div>
 )
)
}
```